# Rails, Simple Form, Nested Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
class Project
  has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions
end
```

I am trying to make an app with rails 4 and Simple Form.

I have models called projects, project_questions and project_answers.

The associations between them are:

**Projects:**

```
has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions
```

**Project questions:**

```
belongs_to :project#, counter_cache: true
has_many :project_answers, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_answers
belongs_to :user
```

**Project answers:**

```
belongs_to :project_question#, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :user
```

**User:**

```
has_many :project_questions
has_many :project_answers

class ProjectQuestions
  belongs_to :project#, counter_cache: true
  has_many :project_answers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_answers
end
```

**ProjectAnswer:**

```
belongs_to :project_question#, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :user
```

My objective is to have a partial on my projects show page which displays the questions and their answers relating to the project and to have a link to another form where you can ask a question or answer one. I am struggling.

In my controllers I have:

**Projects:**

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(project_question_attributes: [:title, :content, :user_id, :project_id,project_answer_attributes: [:answer, :project_question_id]],
```

**Project_question:**

```
def new
  @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new
  @project_id = params[:project_id]
  @project_question.project_answers[0] = ProjectAnswer.new
end
```

**Project_answer:**

```
def new
  @project_answer = ProjectAnswer.new
end

def project_question_params
    params[:project_question].permit(:id, :title, :content, :project_id,   :user_id,project_answer_atttibutes: [:id, :answer, :project_question_id, :user_id])
end
```

Then in my views I have:

**Project#show:**

```
<% if current_user.id ==  @project.creator_id %>
    <%= link_to 'Ask a question', new_project_project_question_path(:project_id => @project.id) %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'project_questions/pqps' %>
```

**Project_question#pqps (a partial):**

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="categorytitle">
            <%= @project_question.try(:title) %>
          </div>
          <div class="generaltext">
            <%= @project_question.try(:content) %>
          </div>
          <span class="editproject">   
              <% if current_user.id == @project.creator_id %>
              <% end %>
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My project_questions form partial is:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <% f.simple_fields_for :project_questions do |f| %>
              <%= f.input :project_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @project_question_id} %>
              <%= f.input :title, label: 'Question:', :label_html => {:class => 'categorytitle'}, placeholder: 'Type your question here', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', class: 'categorytitle'} %>
              <%= f.input :content, label: 'Is there any context or other information?', :label_html => {:class => 'categorytitle'}, placeholder: 'Context might help to answer your question', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', rows: 5, class: 'generalprojecttext'} %>
              <%= f.button :submit %>   
           <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Project_answer#pa (a partial):

```
(not yet written - still trying to get the questions to work)
```

My routes are:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
end
```

When I try this, I get an error in my project_questions form that says:`undefined local variable or method`f' for #<#:0x000001013d8298>`

I can't see where it is talking about f outside the form block.  I have tried adding another line to the form for simple_fields for project and then nesting the project questions form inside of it, but that doesn't change anything.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of this line `<% f.simple_fields_for :project_questions do |f| %>` you should have `<%= simple_form_for :project_questions do |f| %>`

Comment: Thank you - that worked. I don't know where I got the other bit from.

Comment: I will be posting it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line `<% f.simple_fields_for :project_questions do |f| 
%>` to this `<%= simple_form_for :project_questions do |f| %>` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The plataformatec simple_form wiki has a pretty good [instructional page on using nested forms](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models).

(Just as a side note, I find that it's often easier to diagnose problems without using partials. Once everything is working, you can clean-up by refactoring into partials.)

I believe you need to pass a local variable to your partial, so it knows what the first "f" refers to.

```
<%= render 'project_questions/pqps', locals: {f: f} %>
```

(You also may choose to use a different local variable in the partial for project_questions, just so you're always clear what is being referenced in error messages.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've read the wiki several times over. Thanks anyway